# How to replace an unkown amount of repetitions of a pattern in regexp?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, indentation

I am replacing all space indentations in my python files with tab indentations, because for some reasons my indent tool doesn't make the replacement (it does for js, html, css files though).

I am trying to globally replace the pattern with vscode using a regexp, but I can't find the right expression to use. I thought about replacing all four-spaces with tabs: `/    /g`, however at some places in the code there are some special indentation in the middle on an expression that I want to keep. They intend to make the code more readable, and look like this:

```
    a       = 1
    aaaaaaa = 2
    aaaa    = 3
```

Replacing these four-spaces will break the alignment, so I want to keep these space indentations (I might replace them later but for now I don't need to bother doing this).

The new pattern I found is a newline followed by an unknown amount of four-spaces: `/\n(    )*/g`. This searches for all classic indentations, excluding the very specific indentations in the middle of an expression. However I cannot find a way to replace these patterns with the correct amount of tabs: I am not replacing one four-space, I am replacing an unknown amount of four-spaces.

How can I replace an unknown amount of repetitions of a pattern with a regexp?

Comment: It appears your regex "machinery" uses Visual Code; is that correct? You may want to tag your question [visual code] then, since these kind of things for regexes may be different for different languages, IDEs and environments in general.

Comment: You're right, i'll tag it, thx

Comment: Are there still languages & style guides that promote aligning assignments? The ones I know all suggest to *not* have extra spacing for aligned assignments, contrary to the example here.

Comment: This is a personal initiative. I think it is great to do this sometimes.

Comment: Well, until you need an extra variable that has an `obvious_but_rather_long_name`, and you have to do a lot more editing than just adding one line with that variable.

Comment: this is not a norm, just something i do when it seems apropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
(?<=^(?: {4})*) {4}
```

Replace with `\t`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ScZDqJ/1).

Screenshots with the results:

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?<=^(?: {4})*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with start of a line and then any amount of four space strings
- `{4}` - four spaces.

Comment: Amazing regex! Thanks for the magic trick.